# Simple vs complex types in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, types

What’s the easiest way to tell if a variable is simple (float, int, or string) or complex (tuple, list, dictionary, etc)?

I don’t believe “simple” and “complex” are the python vocabulary terms used. But I'd essentially like to quickly determine if a variable is a single element or not (even a single key: value dictionary pair would be not simple for my purposes).

Comment: `isinstance(thing, tuple_of_simple_types)`?

Comment: A string is also a sequence; it's made up of multiple characters. But Python has no "single character" type, so `str` is not really either a primitive or a compound type.

Comment: Please be more specific in your definition of simple and complex types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
myvar = 'a'
type(myvar) in [str, float, int]
>>> True

myvar = {'a': 10}
type(myvar) in [dict, tuple, list]
>>> True
```

Comment: `isinstance(myvar, ...)` is the better way to do this since it will include subtypes

Comment: @wjandrea But subtypes are not necessarily "simple" - e.g. `class A(int): def __init__(self): self.foo = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

`type(object)`  Is what you use to determine the data type.  It's on you to evaluate what you are looking for.  Ali Cirik wrote some basic evaluations.